# impossibility to use PHP exec() with a function in windows7

Tags: php, latex, tex, miktex

I present my problem : I use wampserver 2.4 to make a local site which unable me to create a file `.tex`. Next I want to compile this file (named `devoir.tex`) with MiKTeX so `latex.exe` is in the `bin` directory. But, using `exec()`, I can't create the `.dvi` file and the program never stops. Examples of my differents code :

1. `$path='C:\MiKTeK\miktex\bin\x64\latex.exe devoir.tex';`

   `exec($path);`
2. `exec('start C:\MiKTeK\miktex\bin\x64\latex.exe devoir.tex');`
3. `shell_exec('C:\MiKTeK\miktex\bin\x64\latex.exe  devoir.tex ');`

don't create the `.dvi` file.

Ten years ago, I did this site with easyphp and was ok. But now, I don't understand the problem : a syntactic one ? other due to windows7 ?

Comment: (1) What do the various `exec` calls return?

Comment: (2) Where does `devoir.tex` live?  In most cases, the "current directory" is the location of the main script.  If your filename is relative (ie: if it doesn't start with a slash, or a backslash in Windows), it should usually be relative to that location.

Comment: cHao : how can I know what exec calls return ? they never stop. The file devoir.tex is in the same directory as index.php of my site.

Comment: Call `phpinfo()` and see if safe mode is on; if so, you can't run `exec()` or `shell_exec()`. I believe it is on by default in wampserver.

Comment: safe mode is off in my php.ini.

Comment: And when you run the program from the command line, typing exactly what you pass to `*exec`, it works?

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution on the php.net comment [sbourazanis](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/function.exec.php#86438)

```
/**
 * Fonction Exec marche mal sous Windows, donc il en faut une autre 
 * fr.php.net/manual/fr/function.exec.php#86438
 * @param string $cmd
 * @return boolean
 */
public function _exec($cmd) 
{ 
    $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell"); 
    $oExec = $WshShell->Run($cmd, 0, true); //0 pour avoir une fenêtre cachée
                                            //true pour attendre la fin de l'éxécution
                                            //cf. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29

    return $oExec == 0 ? true : false; 
}
```